# repeat a function every n seconds while counting down n minutes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, timer

What I am trying to achieve is to repeat a function every n seconds while I have a second timer at the background running like a clock so when n minutes has passed the script is terminated. I know about treading.timer, but it doesnt work when I have 2 timers. Any ideas are welcome since I am fairly new to python.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import datetime

def somefunction(x):
    return x


x = True
while x:
    a = datetime.datetime.now().hour

    if a < 22:
        time.sleep(1)
        somefunction(x)

    else:
        x = False
```

or:

script1.py

```
import datetime

a = datetime.datetime.now().hour
```

script2.py

```
from script1 import a
import time



def somefunction(x):
    return x



while a < 22: #execute function as long it is less than 22.00, else stop

    time.sleep(1)
    somefunction(x)
```

Or if you have any other background source, it would be good to know what it is.

Comment: And how does this run parallel (in background) with the other code?